# Django_python project

Tags: python, django

I have been having this erro with my django project.please help...

> ValueError at / ModelForm has no model class specified.

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUp

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        models=SignUp
        fields=['full_name','email','matric_no']
def clean_email(self):
    '''
    This function validates the email field in the form
    '''
    email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    email_base, provider= email.split('@')
    domain, extension=provider.split('.')
    if not domain=='gmail':
        raise forms.ValidationError("please enter a valid .gmail email. address")
    if not extension == 'edu':
        raise forms.ValidationError("please enter a valid email address with the correct .edu extenstion")
    return email
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .form import SignUpForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    title='My Title {0}'.format(request.user)
    form=SignUpForm()
    context={
        "template_title":title,
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

> ValueError at / ModelForm has no model class specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a typo. It is `model` not `models`.

```
class Meta:
    model = SignUp
```